# How can I remove last dot (period) from a string in bash

Tags: string, bash

In a bash file I get an input argument `$1`. It may contains a dot at its end or not like (`test.` or `test`)

I would like to have `test` in both cases to add an extension to it and create for example `test.py` from it

Comment: Okay, the questions are similar, however its hard to find ending with slash when you search for ending with DOT. But why downvote?!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parameter expansion has an operator `%` to trim characters from the end of an expansion.

```
$ set test.
$ echo "$1"
test.
$ echo "${1%.}"
test
```

If there is no trailing dot, the expansion is left unchanged:

```
$ set test
$ echo "${1%.}"
test
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [parameter expansions](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-bash-parameters/) like this :

```
yourVar=${1/.}
echo $yourVar
```

Result :

```
$ ./test.sh "test."
> test
$ ./test.sh "test" 
> test
```

Comment: assuming input could have multiple periods this appears to remove just the first period, eg: `set test.1.2.3.. ; echo ${1/.}` => `test1.2.3..`